# How to restrict Google Custom Search to specific url prefixes?

Tags: google-custom-search

If I go to the Google CSE control panel (https://www.google.com/cse/all) I see a list of my custom search engines.

When I click on one I can see in the list the option "**sites to search**". There I can list

- example.com/cool-path
- example.com/awesome-path
- etc

How do I use the API to do the same? To add multiple domains, sites, or paths to the search? I can't find any documentation specifying this behavior.

Answer (score -1):

The API will connect to a search engine that is specified on your custom search panel.

So you create the search engines you need (each with it's own list of sites to search) and then you connect to whichever one you need using the API using the engine's unique code

Comment: As Nick suggested, that's the most common way to do it - via Control Panel. If you still want to create the engine fully programatically, you can use the Linkes Engine mechanism: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/linked_cse